# Navegar entre telas

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto no `Android Studio`, usando `drawer navigation`. E em um dos `Fragments` preciso que tenha uma navegação de 2 telas.

Como eu faço para navegar entre duas telas, ou seja, quando deslizar sobre uma tela, abrir outra tela e ter essa navegação entre 2 layout.

Comment: Se não me engano tens de usar `onFling` nos eventos do detetor de gestos.

Comment: Acredito que você esteja falando sobre ViewPager ? confira o link e veja se eh isso http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas na verdade preciso apenas que passe de uma tela para outra sem usar botões, apenas deslizando. Acho que o ideal seria um método que ao deslizar(para a direita) sobre uma tela ela chame a outra.

Comment: Justamente isso que postei, Viewpager não tem botoes.

Comment: sim mas como eu implemento isso em um drawer navigation? quando for selecionado uma opção, por exemplo um endereço abrir um endereço e ao deslizar para a direita abrir outra tela com o endereço 2...

Comment: @DanielKchevi tens de explicar melhor o teu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Para este caso, pode ser usado [**ViewPager**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). Na [documentação do Android](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) possui um exemplo pronto para *download*. Veja a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]